# Creating multiple Angular components dynamically

Tags: angular

I have an array of data objects:

```
const arr = [
   {type: 'CustomA', id: 1, label: 'foo'},
   {type: 'CustomB', src: './images/some.jpg'}
   {type: 'CustomX', firstName: 'Bob', secondName:'Smith'}
]
```

These objects will always have a `type` but the rest of the properties on each will be specific to that type.
I have a component set up that can accept and display each of the possible data objects, doing whatever parsing and internal logic is required.
I want to look through that list, check the `type` of each object that I find and add the relevant component to the page. So, if I find `type: 'CustomA` I can add a `CustomADisplay` component to the page and pass it the data object to work with.

How best to achieve this when I don't know in advance how many items will be in that list or what their types will be?
Basically, who can I dynamically create and add components to page while the app is running.
I am currently playing around with `ViewContainerRef` as per the docs but this seems to require a target element in the template and until I get my data I'm not going to know how many of these are needed.

Hope that makes sense. Any advice very gratefully received.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader this might be helpful

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet could be usefull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you are thinking off in something like this:

HTML for your array

```
arr = [
      {type: 'CustomA', id: 1, label: 'foo'},
      {type: 'CustomB', src: './images/some.jpg'}
      {type: 'CustomX', firstName: 'Bob', secondName:'Smith'}
];
```

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of arr" [ngSwitch]="item.type">

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="CustomA">
       <app-custom-a-display [data]="item"><app-custom-a-display>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="CustomB">
       <app-custom-b-display [data]="item"><app-custom-b-display>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
       <app-custom-x-display [data]="item"><app-custom-x-display>
    </ng-container>

  </ng-container>
```

TS example for your CustomADisplay:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-a-display',
  templateUrl: './custom-a-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-a-display.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomADisplayComponent {
private _localData;
@Input()
get data() {
   return _localData;
}
set data(data) {
    this._localData= data;   
}

constructor() {
// you will have your {type: 'CustomA', id: 1, label: 'foo'}
// accesible in 'data' variable
}

   
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know but that looks promising. I've not come across `ngSwitch` or `<ng-container>` before so I'll look into this and hopefully come back and present you with a nice green tick later

Comment: Yep, this has done the job. Cheers :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped

Answer (score 5):

The above answer gets the job done but just like with any other switch case you will need to keep on adding more switch conditions for each type. Like talha mentioned in the comments it might be better to use [dynamic component](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) rendering. Although this solution requires more configuration but it should be easier to manage in the long run.
Essentially something like this. heres the working [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhtee7?file=src/app/app.component.html).

```
const datas = [
   {type: 'CustomA', id: 1, label: 'foo'},
   {type: 'CustomB', src: './images/some.jpg'}
   {type: 'CustomX', firstName: 'Bob', secondName:'Smith'}
]
```

```
import AComponent from 'wherever';
import BComponent from 'wherever';
import XComponent from 'wherever';
// constants file
export const TypeMappedComponents = {
  CustomA: AComponent,
  CustomB: BComponent,
  CustomX: XComponent
}
```

```
// dynamic-renderer.component.html
<ng-template appRenderDynamically></ng-template>
```

```
//dynamic-renderer.component.ts
import { TypeMappedComponents } from '../constants';
import { RenderDynamicallyDirective } from '../render-dynamically.directive';

@Component(...all the decorator stuff)
export class DynamicRendererComponent {
  _data: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  componentType = '';
  @Input() set data(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
    this._data = data;
    this.componentType = data.type as string;
    this.componentType && this.createDynamicComponent(this.componentType);
  }
  @ViewChild(RenderDynamicallyDirective, { static: true })
  renderDynamic: RenderDynamicallyDirective;

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  createDynamicComponent(type: string) {
    const component = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(
      TypeMappedComponents[type]
    );
    this.renderDynamic.vcr.clear();
    const componentRef = this.renderDynamic.vcr.createComponent(
      component
    ) as any;
    componentRef.instance.data = this._data;
  }
}
```

and then you just loop it and pass the data to dynamic-renderer. This should dynamically create the component according to the type.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of datas">
  <app-dynamic-renderer [data]="data"></app-dynamic-renderer>
</ng-container>
```

Heres the `renderDynamicallyDirective` which places the component into the view.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appRenderDynamically]'
})
export class RenderDynamicallyDirective {
  constructor(public vcr: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Although this code is longer than the switch case, its more of a one time effort. Since if you have a new type and new component to go along with it you just need to created the required component. then add the new type and the component associated with it to the `TypeMappedComponent`.

Comment: I think this solution is the best approach! Maybe you could try also something with ViewChildren to avoid the individual wrapper component but it's already correct!

Comment: Yes, this is a great solution. One question for @KZoeps : this will clear old components. Let's say we want user to switch between components, is there a way to keep them all in the DOM and display only the one required? Or is that a bad idea to begin with? If HTML components are in the DOM, the switching is smooth and fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of the answer provided by @KZoeps,

```
// dynamic-renderer.component.html
<ng-template #container></ng-template>
```

```
//dynamic-renderer.component.ts
import { TypeMappedComponents } from '../constants';
import { RenderDynamicallyDirective } from '../render-dynamically.directive';

@Component(...all the decorator stuff)
export class DynamicRendererComponent {
  _data: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  componentType = '';
  @Input() set data(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
    this._data = data;
    this.componentType = data.type as string;
    this.componentType && this.createDynamicComponent(this.componentType);
  }

   @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false })

  
  component!: ViewContainerRef;

 
  createDynamicComponent(type: string) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const componentRef = this.component.createComponent(
        TypeMappedComponents[type]
      ) as any;
     componentRef.instance.data = this._data;
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

and then you just loop it and pass the data to dynamic-renderer. This should dynamically create the component according to the type.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of datas">
  <app-dynamic-renderer [data]="data"></app-dynamic-renderer>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I only replace the timeout by a call in ngAfterViewInit.